# Rails/Rspec Tests Failing due to Broken Pipe...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I recently updated some gems in my application (unfortunately I did not do them one by one) and now all of my tests are failing with the following error:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe
  occurred at /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@xxx/gems/capybara-webkit-0.12.1/lib/capybara/driver/webkit/connection.rb:21:in `write'
```

I am using:

- rails 3.2.7/3.2.8
- rspec
- spork
- postgres
- factory girl
- memcached

And obviously plenty others... I can provide additional details as required (I'm not sure what to post)

I have also tried:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rspec spec
```

Comment: Looks like something is causing capybara-webkit to break. I'd suggest trying to specifying an older version (0.11.0?) in your Gemfile and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion cheeseweasel.  I will give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Downgraded capybara to 0.11.0 - no effect.  Everything is still failing on broken pipe!!

Comment: I'm out of ideas sorry. This issue: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/68 says that the Broken pipe error means that the webkit server has crashed - "A broken pipe happens when the webkit_server binary crashes, so it always indicates a bug in capybara-webkit. Unfortunately, it's frequently difficult to find out what actually caused it to crash.", I'm guessing you must have a conflict with one of your recently updated gems, open an issue maybe and see if you can get some help in there.

Comment: No problem - thanks for looking at this. My experience so far with these cryptic error messages is that they can be totally unrelated to the actual problem in the application.  I just noticed last nigth that there was something funky going on with an extension to the database, so I'm going to chase that down to see if it fixes the Capybara/Rspec issues.  Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `sleep` after each test.

I had a similar problem with acceptance tests with rspec

All tests are green when they are run separately. But when I try to run all the tests at once they will break somewhere in the middle

Adding `sleep` after each test helps me (but I have no idea *why*):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.after(:each, js: true) { sleep 0.1 }
end
```